# Kant: 7 + 5 = 12 and concepts

Tags: kant

I have already read several posts on this topic but I have some other questions.

1. According to Kant,

   > 5 + 7 = 12

   is a *synthetic a priori judgement*.

   I want to know what the *judgement* really is. Is it `5 + 7 = 12`, or `5 + 7` (which is *judged* to be 12) ? If it's the first case, we have to know 5 concepts (5,+,7,=,12) to determine if the judgement is true.
2. Kant says, nothing allows us to know 5 + 7 equals 12 without synthetic judgement. But that depends on how we see the word "concept". The number "5" has no meaning if it's not in a context (real number, etc.), and in real number context, we have axioms to know 5 + 7 = 12 (by ++ operator). We can't separate "+" and "5" in different contexts. For example, in a strong-type language, it is meaningless to add a float and an integer.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second question- the concept "numbers" doesn't inherently include the concept "mathematics".

Comment: I would mediate a bit over the claim that *the number "5" has no meaning if it's not in a context (real number, etc.)*. This is mathematical structuralism (Shapiro), but it's not without its problems. For me, 5 as natural number and 5 as real number, are the same 5. And the fact that strongly typed programming languages have problems with this isn't such a convincing argument IMHO. A computer is a finite state machine and can't represent all real numbers anyway.

Comment: Anyway, I guess 2. is a strong assumption in favor of mathematical structuralism, that was not in Kant's mind when he wrote that 5 + 7 = 12 is a synthetic judgement (btw, the whole formula is the judgment) .

Answer (score 1):

> what the *judgement* really is ?

A *judgement* is a mental act. It is characterized by the attitude (of the actor making it) towards the represented object (its "content").

When we acknowledge or reject an representation (or the content of a thought), we make a judgement.

The linguistic act that corresponds to a judgement is an [assertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act#Classifying_illocutionary_speech_acts).

---

In term of [Kant's phylosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-judgment/), we may say (very roughly) that we have a judgement when two *concepts* (or representations) are united in thought .

According to Kant, the distinction between *a priori* and *a posteriori* is an epistemic one : it concerns the basis of the *knowledge* of a fact.

*A priori* knowledge is not based upon empirical observation but upon reason alone.

For Kant, all mathematical judgement (we today say: statements) are *synthetic* and *a priori*.

Obviously, Kant assumes that arithmetical concepts have meaning. *Numbers* are [counting numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting#Counting_in_mathematics), i.e. "number of ...".

And *sum* is the abstract concept related to juxtaposition [see *CPR*, B14-16 [English transl. page 144](http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/kant-first-critique-cambridge.pdf)]:

> We have to go outside these concepts, and call in the aid of the intuition which corresponds to  one of them, our five fingers, for instance, or five points, 
>   adding to the concept of 7, unit by unit, the five given in intuition. For starting with the number 7, and for the concept of 5 calling in the aid of the fingers of my hand as intuition, I now add one by one to the number 7 the units which I previously took together to form the number 5, and with the aid of that figure [the hand] see the number 12 come into being.

---

See also [Brentano's Theory of Judgement](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/brentano-judgement/)

Comment: Ok thank you. So if I understood well the judgement (statement) is 5 + 7 = 12. That contains 5 concepts. And I don't see why we can't get 12 out of 5 and 7 as long as we know the concept of "+" and "="

Comment: So, what is a number?  Is it something out of experience (in which they are a posteriori concept)?  Is it something deduced from axioms?  In that case, we aren't equating to different concepts of "7+5" and "12", and we do not have a synthetic proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Why is judgement or intuition required here? Perhaps for some things but ever since Russell and Whitehead certainly not for Mathematics.  To save some typing please consider 1+2=3 which means s(0) + s(s(0)) = s(s(s(0))); which can be proven by repeated application of Peano's axioms for addition: s(0) + s(s(0)) = s(s(0) + s(0)) = s(s(s(0) + 0))) = s(s(s(0))) QED.